# Running Sencha Touch app on Java Eclipse & Android Emulator on Windows 8 (without phonegap)

Tags: senchatouch-2.4

I am getting trouble in running sencha touch 2 app on android emulator (without using cordova/phonegap) on windows 8 using .

Below is the list of packages installed on DEV machine:

- **1.** JRE v1.7
- **2.** Sencha Touch v2.4.1 SDK
- **3.** Sencha SDK Tools 2.0.0 beta
- **4.** Sencha Cmd 5.1.2
- **5.** Ruby 2.0.0
- **6.** Chrome (Browser)
- **7.** Web Server - Both IIS 8 & XAMPP
- **8.** Android SDK 23.0.6
- **9.** Eclipse IDE (integrated with VJET Library & ExtJSTL 4.2)
- **10.** Android ADT Manager (installed emulator snapshots targeting os2.2 & 5.1)

"MyApp" project runs perfectly on chrome browser when hosted on IIS 8 & XAMPP (apache). But not able to figure out steps to run the same on android emulator. So far followed below mentioned steps, leading to unsuccessful attempts:

1. sencha app build native [Command Successful]
2. sencha app build -run native [Command Successful]
3. sencha app build package [Command Successful]

Started emulator instance from eclipse (avd) and executed command **sencha app build -run native**, but the app doesn't execute on emulator instance.

Followed steps mentioned in post (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?215210-how-to-run-sencha-touch-app-on-android-emulator-on-windows) but still facing issues.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

do u want to run it as website for mobile? 
as u are saying, you don't want to use cordoav/phonegap.

If u just want to run on Mobile Browser U can use Netbeans. It has a very simple feature to allow a html5 application to be run on Mobile browser
all U have to do is
1. Create HTML5 Project in netbeans
2. Run command "sencha app build native"
3. copy all files & folders form directory cordova->www which exist in your sencha app directory
4. Paste it into your HTML5 Project directory
5. Choose The Browser option in netbeans and run

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nitish for your suggestions. But this is not what my query was all about. I was trying to figure out a way of running sencha touch app on emulator without compiling it to native app following steps mentioned in post: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?215210-how-to-run-sencha-touch-app-on-android-emulator-on-windows.

Anyways, to run sencha touch app on emulator I had to create native android app using cordova/phonegap wrapper. To run sencha touch app (which is mobile web portal equivalent), it is required to be wrapped inside native app (android, ios, etc) followed by app signing and APK / IPA file generation.